# Tableview Updating wrong cell

Tags: swift

[image]

I made a like button problem is  when the like button is tapped the values update only the first tableview cell even if I clicked the second cell it will update the values of likes in the first tableview cell. The values update properly on firestore for each individual cell but its being loaded wrong

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    motivationThoughts.count
   }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DailyThoughtCELL", for: indexPath) as? dailyMotivationTableViewCell

    cell!.generateCellsforDailymotivation(_MotivationdataMODEL: self.motivationThoughts[indexPath.row], objectID: self.motivationThoughts[indexPath.row].motiveID)

        //cell!.postID = self.motivationThoughts[indexPath.row].motiveID //this works and updates the value
    //cell!.generateLikeCell(objectID: self.motivationThoughts[indexPath.row].motiveID)
        return cell!
   }





func loaddailymotivation() {
    FirebaseReferece(.MotivationDAILY).addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in

        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            if (diff.type == .added) { // this line means if the chage that happened in the document was equal to added something

                let data = diff.document.data()
                  print("we have\(snapshot.documents.count) documents in this array")

                  let dailyMotivationID = data["objectID"] as! String

                  let dailymotivationTitle = data["Motivation title"] as! String //calls the data thats heald inside of motivation title in firebase
                  let dailyMotivationScripture = data["daily motivation scripture"] as! String //calls the data thats heald inside of Motivation script in firebase

                  let dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes = data["Number of likes in daily motivation post"]as! Int



                 let MdataModel = motivationDailyModel(RealMotivationID: dailyMotivationID, RealmotivationTitle: dailymotivationTitle, RealmotivationScrip: dailyMotivationScripture, RealmotivationNumberOfLikes: dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes)

                self.motivationThoughts.append(MdataModel)

            }
            /*
            I thinkyou need a method that identifies the item that needs to be modified in the array, and replace/modify it. If you add a new object, you have one more element in your table*/
            if (diff.type == .modified) {
                print("Modified data: \(diff.document.data())")

       let newdata = diff.document.data()

       let objectID = newdata["objectID"] as! String // we get the object id of the uodated item
                //self.GrabThatDamnstring(grabIt: objectID)
                //self.incrementLikes(NewobjectID: objectID) //write a function to grab the string from the certain post and then send it to dailymotivationviewcell into the function increment likes so so it can update the specific objectID

        guard let dailymotivationIndex = self.motivationThoughts.firstIndex(where: {_ in objectID == objectID}) else { return }



       var dailymotivation = self.motivationThoughts[dailymotivationIndex]

       let dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes = newdata["Number of likes in daily motivation post"] as! Int

       dailymotivation.motivationNumberOfLikes = dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes

       self.motivationThoughts[dailymotivationIndex] = dailymotivation

                //  here you will receive if any change happens in your data add it to your array as you want
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the  uitableview cellcode

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Firebase
import JGProgressHUD

class dailyMotivationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    //numberOfLikesGenerator()
    self.holdView.layer.cornerRadius = 19
    self.likedbuttonFIlled.isHidden = true

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}




  @IBOutlet weak var holdView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var likedbuttonFIlled: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var likeSavedButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var DMtextLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var DMtitleLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var numberOfLikesLabel: UILabel!


//MARK: VARS/LETS
var postID : String!
var MotivationData : motivationDailyModel!
let hud = JGProgressHUD(style: .light)


//MARK: IBACTIONS
@IBAction func likeButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

if (Auth.auth().currentUser != nil || AccessToken.current != nil) {
        changeLikeButtonMode()
     //update like number and update like number on firebase

}
else{
           hud.textLabel.text = "Please Login to Continue!"
           hud.show(in: self.contentView)
           hud.dismiss(afterDelay: 3.0)
           hud.indicatorView = JGProgressHUDErrorIndicatorView()
    //no user login so pull up login view
    }



    //MARK: TODO when this button is tapped ALSO WANT TO STORE THIS SNAPSHOT INTO AN ARRAY THAT WE WILL SHOW IN OUR SAVED VIEW CONTROLLEr
}


//call this function from motivation daily viewcontroller and it will also have the item that was tapped
func incrementLikes(){

    //MARK: WE NEED TO FIND OUT HOW WE GET THE UUID FOR THE CERTAIN POS
    FirebaseReferece(.MotivationDAILY).document(postID).updateData(["Number of likes in daily motivation post":FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))]) { (error) in
             if error != nil {
                 print(error!.localizedDescription)
             } else {
                 print("successfully incremented data!")
             }
         }
     }



  func changeLikeButtonMode(){
      // so if likedbutton is tapped and the heart isnt red that means that the tag  is  = 0 so its gnna show the red heard and then also change the tag to 1 but when it is tapped again its going to change the tag to 0  and removed the red heart
              if likeSavedButton.tag == 0 //means its empty
              {
                incrementLikes()
                self.likedbuttonFIlled.isHidden = false
                likeSavedButton.tag = 1

              }else {

            self.likedbuttonFIlled.isHidden = true
                likeSavedButton.tag = 0

              }
  }




//MARK: FUNCTIONS
func generateCellsforDailymotivation(_MotivationdataMODEL : motivationDailyModel,objectID : String!) {
    DMtextLabel.text = _MotivationdataMODEL.motivationDailyScripture
    DMtitleLabel.text = _MotivationdataMODEL.motivationTitle
    numberOfLikesLabel.text = "\(String(_MotivationdataMODEL.motivationNumberOfLikes))"
    postID = objectID

}
```

}

Comment: Can you share the code for tableview didSelectRowAt:

Comment: @Dale I don't have didselectRowAt am I suppose too?

Comment: How are you implementing the button tap?

Comment: I call it in the tableview cell so increment likes takes place when the  inaction like button is tapped

Comment: then in tableviewcontroller that's where we handle loading the tableview and calling cellforRowat

Comment: You should share that code too

Comment: okay ive shared it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in your guard statement always evaluates to true

```
   guard let dailymotivationIndex = self.motivationThoughts.firstIndex(where: {_ in objectID == objectID}) else { return }
```

Try this instead

```
   guard let dailymotivationIndex = self.motivationThoughts.firstIndex(where: { $0.RealMotivationID == objectID}) else { return }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate you taking time out of your day to help me I didn't even realize that it was always returning true